# List of objects as argument in OrderbyDesceding linq method Asp.Net core 2.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-2.0

I have two modal classes:

1. Conversations

   ```
   public long Id 
   public string SenderId
   public string RecieverId
   public virtual List<Message> Messages
   public virtual User User
   ```
2. Messages

   ```
   public long Id
   public string MessageBody
   public long ConversationId
   public string SenderId 
   public DateTime CreatedDate
   ```

I want to get all conversations with `OrderbyDescending` on Message `CreatedDate`.

I mean to sort conversation at top in which last message is latest by created date. Like:

```
var conversations = _context.Conversations
    .Include(x => x.Messages)
    .Include(x => x.Users)
    .Where(x => x.RecieverId== userId)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Messages.Any(x => x.CreatedDate))
    .ToList();
```

But in this way i can't write `OrderByDescending` statement.

Please give me suggestions if you can.

Hope so someone understands my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should order by the "Latest" message in the conversation so you need to order by the "Highest" date in every message, this is achieved using the linq `Max()` method.
See if it may help you:

```
 .OrderByDescending(conversation => conversation.Messages.Max(message => message.CreatedDate)).ToList();
```